# django user model - when do i need it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have one understanding probem:

I want to create user profile for my page, which will have many attributes. But since I am new to User Model of django's auth, i dont know if i can extend that model with new coming attributes that i set for user profile. e.g. address, age, ...

if not, why is User Model there? is it only for auth purposes? how do I handle and differentiate these two User models?

Sample Case:
user wants to log in, I check the permission with auth's user model and set some relation between django's user model and mine? I just kind of confused here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall try to explain in the perspective of pre-django 1.5

The django's auth models provides a set of "convenience" methods like login, logout, password reset, etc for you which work seamlessly. It is a very common scenario to have more fields - so One approach would be to create a userprofile model, which either `inherits` from the django auth user model, or has a `OneToOne` relationship on the same. This way, you do not have to reimplement some of the already implemented features. In addition, there is `groups` and `permissions` models in the package which add  a whole layer of functionality in terms of user permissionsing.

example:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 class MyCustomProfile(User):
     #inherits all the attributes of default `User` models
     #additional models here.
```

OR

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 class MyCustomProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
     #additional models here.
```

This way, you can use the all the features and build on top of it.

This has changed a little bit in django-1.5 which lets users have Custom fields, which saves you from creating a `UserProfile` model on top of the already existing `User` model.

Comment: great, thank you for clear information. I really love this language

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.5 you can create your own User Model with your custom fields. And tell Django to use that model for auth.

Link to documentation: [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

**Update:**
If you are using Django 1.4, then [django-primate](https://github.com/aino/django-primate) can help you to define custom user model.

Comment: cool, thanks. i am using django 1.4 however the logic is almost same

Answer (score 1):

Derive your class from the user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyCustomUser( User ):
    # my properties here
    # my custom methods here
```

Then you need a custom backend to handle passing your custom user class instead of the regular user so that you can access the properties of that custom user class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
from my.app.models import MyCustomUser

class CustomUserModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = MyCustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Player.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return None #Password was wrong

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return MyCustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except Player.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then add the backend to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` tuple in your `settings.py`.  You can customize it further, this is a *simple* implementation.